# how to deal with changes in LLVM metadata.h

Tags: c++, metadata, llvm, llvm-ir

In the LLVM version 3.6 they have changed the metadata class a lot and they have split the metadata from value.
so my previous code based on 3.5 version doesn't work anymore. I am having difficulties upgrading my code. Can anybody help.

e.g. : previous code :

```
MDNode *record;
Value *undVal = record->getOperand(1);
Type *type_hint = undVal->getType();
```

Does anyone know how to upgrade this code to make it 3.6 compatible ?

I tried this :

```
MDNode *record;
const MDOperand &undVal = record->getOperand(1);
Type *type_hint = undVal->getType();
```

But it doesn't work. Results in compile errors saying

> 'getType' : is not a member of 'llvm::Metadata'

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
MDNode *record;
Value *undVal = dyn_cast<ValueAsMetadata>(record->getOperand(1))->getValue();
```

@sadeq suggestion wasn't compiling for me, but was definitely as step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried dyn_cast<>, like this:

```
Value* undval = dyn_cast<Value>(record->getoperand(1));
Type* type_hint;
if(undval) type_hint = undVal->hetType();
```

Comment: For now my code compiles, but I have to attach the debugger to test this code out. Don't know if I will get any runtime errors.